# Micron NAND (MT29F2G08ABAEAWP): Cannot successfully flash first block (address 0x0)

Tags: u-boot

We are trying to get our Micron NAND flash chip ([MT29F2G08ABAEAWP](http://www.micron.com/parts/nand-flash/mass-storage/mt29f2g08abaeawp-e)) working. We are using u-boot as bootloader and our main processor is a [TI DM8148](http://www.ti.com/product/tms320dm8148). For evaluation we are using [this](http://www.ti.com/tool/tmdxevm8148) evaluation module.

Now, the flash itself gets recognized by u-boot as 8-bit 2Gb NAND (which is correct). I'm able to flash 1st stage u-boot to `0x0` using the following uboot commands:

```
// select BCH8 as HW ECC
nandecc hw 2

// erase the first block
nand erase 0x0 0x20000

// write the content from RAM address 0x81000000 to the
// first flash block (0x0)
nand write.i 0x81000000 0x0 0x20000
```

However, when I try to read from that address using

```
nand read.i 0x81000000 0x0 0x20000
```

I get a lot of `ECC: Uncorrectable` errors. Choosing another ECC algorithm doesn't help. Booting from NAND (via ROM boot) doesn't work.

Any ideas?

**Update:**
Writing and reading every other block works like charm. Just the first one (Block 0) has those issues.

I know that issue is very specific. But I'm hoping that someone else might have had the same problems.

Thanks and greeting,
SamuelTee

Comment: Did you read the datasheet for the NAND chip?  Is it ONFI? Perhaps the first page is the `parameter page`?

Comment: @sawdust Yes, it is supposed to be ONFI 1.0 compliant.